# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null. Ошибка в Firefox

Tags: jquery, javascript, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить данную ошибку. Для сайта есть файл со скриптом, который подключается, насколько я понял, проблема в нём. Вот файл скрипта:

```
    function fadeToDiv(){
      $('#les8_ex6').fadeTo(2000, 0);

}

$(document).ready(fadeToDiv());

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('logo').className += ' loaded';
}
```

Comment: Html код покажите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, метод `getElementById` не может найти элемент с `id`, равным  `logo`.

Comment: Спасибо, нашёл ошибку)